# How to copy directory to destination path using yeomon generator?

Tags: node.js, typescript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have all the files in templates directory that needs to copy to destination path when i run command yo my-generator and in below index.js `writing` method i tried to copy templates to templates it throws error , what is correct way to achieve this tassk using yeoman ?

index.js

```
'use strict';
const Generator = require('yeoman-generator');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const yosay = require('yosay');

module.exports = class extends Generator {
  prompting() {
    // Have Yeoman greet the user.
    this.log(
      yosay(
        `Welcome to the epic ${chalk.red(
          "generator-cvsdigital-sdk-nodeapp-generator"
        )} generator!`
      )
    );

    const prompts = [
      {
        type: "input",
        name: "name",
        message: "Your project name",
        // Defaults to the project's folder name if the input is skipped
        default: this.appname
      }
    ];

    return this.prompt(prompts).then(props => {
      // To access props later use this.props.someAnswer;
      this.props = props;
    });
  }

  writing() {
    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath("package.json"),
      this.destinationPath("package.json")
    );
    this.fs.copyTpl(
      this.templatePath("templates"),
      this.destinationPath("templates")
    );
  }

  install() {
    this.installDependencies();
  }
};
```

error

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Trying to copy from a source that does not exist: /Users/z243545/Documents/Projects/Microservices/generator-cvsdigital-sdk-nodeapp-generator/generators/app/templates/templates
    at EditionInterface.exports.copy (/Users/z243545/Documents/Projects/Microservices/generator-cvsdigital-sdk-nodeapp-generator/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/lib/actions/copy.js:48:3)
    at EditionInterface.module.exports [as copyTpl] (/Users/z243545/Documents/Projects/Microservices/generator-cvsdigital-sdk-nodeapp-generator/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/lib/actions/copy-tpl.js:29:8)
    at module.exports.writing (/Users/z243545/Documents/Projects/Microservices/generator-cvsdigital-sdk-nodeapp-generator/generators/app/index.js:38:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/z243545/Documents/Projects/Microservices/generator-cvsdigital-sdk-nodeapp-generator/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:399:25)
    at /Users/z243545/Documents/Projects/Microservices/generator-cvsdigital-sdk-nodeapp-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:49:25
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/z243545/Documents/Projects/Microservices/generator-cvsdigital-sdk-nodeapp-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:26:19
    at self.env.runLoop.add.completed (/Users/z243545/Documents/Projects/Microservices/generator-cvsdigital-sdk-nodeapp-generator/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:400:11)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
```

[image]